# Problems displaying plist in UITableView using storyboards? (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, plist

I have done this on another project before and got it working then, but I cannot find out why this piece of my programming will not work. 
It displays the table without any of the plist data on it. 
Please take a look through my code to see if you can spot where I have made a mistake, thanks.

```
#import "MarketViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MarketViewController ()

@end

@implementation MarketViewController
@synthesize shares, shareValues, number, shareName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    self.navigationItem.title = @"Stock Market";
    NSString *sharesFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shares" ofType:@"plist"];

    shares = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: sharesFile];
    shareValues = [shares objectForKey:@"Share Values"];
    shareName = [shares objectForKey:@"Share Names"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

    self.menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, 34, 24);
    [_menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:self.menuBtn];



}

//Table View

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [shares count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    NSString *nameOfShare = [shareName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *valueOfShare = [shareValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = valueOfShare;
    cell.textLabel.text = nameOfShare;
    return cell;
    self.title = @"Stock Market";


}

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

My h. file is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MarketViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *menuBtn;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *CurrentDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *shares;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *shareValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *number;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *shareName;
- (NSString*)filePath;
- (void)openDB;



@end
```

Comment: Are you sure that "Share Values" & "Share Names" are actually items in your plist file? Why not also name them with proper naming conventions?

Comment: Some info from the debugger would help diagnose this.  Drop a breakpoint in numberOfRowsInSection and type "po shares" in the debugger to make sure the objects you're expecting are there.

Comment: I went through it there and did notice an issue where i had some called 'Share Value' without the s, but when i ran on simulator it still give me blank table? Im actually new to xcode so unsure how to go about doing your suggestion @stevex

Comment: Click in the margin to the left of the "return [shares count];" line.  You should see a blue arrow appear in the line; this is a breakpoint, and asks the debugger to pause your program's execution when it gets to this point.  Run your app, and it should pause there.  Then in the console window at the bottom of Xcode, you can type "po shares", which calls the description method of the shares array and prints what it returns to the console.  You should see a list of all the objects in the array; if there are none, that's a problem.

Comment: I inserted a breakpoint where you suggested, ran simulator, and everything looks the same as it was. In the output section there is no writing? Where abouts should i type 'po shares'? thanks

Comment: Check to make sure that in your corresponding `.h` file for this posted code: Make sure that the `@property`s for shareName and shareValue are set to `strong` instead of `weak`. If it works, let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Sorry only getting back. I checked and they are set to (nonatomic, strong) I will display my h. file for you to see. Any other suggestions would be appreciated as I am running out of time and cant get past this barrier, thanks.